# OpenSSL pkcs12 export fails when specifying CSR file

Tags: openssl, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I'm attempting to create a p12 file for use with PushSharp to send iOS push notifications. I used this exact process a year ago to renew our certificates and it worked fine; but now it's failing at the final step.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Create a certificate signing request in Keychain Access, as a file named `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest`
2. Export the private key from Keychain Access, saving the file as `private_key.p12`
3. Go to developer.apple.com, create a production Apple Push Services certificate using the CSR file from step 1, download the file as `aps.cer`
4. Run the following commands in a shell (pretty much identical to what one finds on some other Stack Overflow posts):

```bash
openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform DER -out app_cert.pem -outform PEM

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out private_key.pem -in private_key.p12

openssl rsa -out private_key_noenc.pem -in private_key.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -in app_cert.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -name "MyAppName" -out pushsharp.p12
```

The final openssl command fails with this error:

> unable to load certificates

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong; this is all in a script that worked fine a year ago. I was able to get the `openssl pkcs12 -export` command to succeed by removing the `-certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` argument, but I believe the p12 file generated by this will not work with PushSharp.

Comment: It looks incorrect to give a certificate signing request file (`CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest`) as a value for `-certfile`. The error seems appropriate, since that is not a certificate file. What is the purpose of including that file?

Comment: These openssl commands are part of a script that we've used for a couple of years as part of the process for renewing certificates for Apple push notification services. Specifically to generate a .p12 file that is compatible with the PushSharp library on our .NET web servers. If I recall correctly, it needs to be done this way for PushSharp to work correctly; I haven't had a chance yet to test it with a p12 generated with that `-certfile` param.

Comment: Sorry, typo: I haven't had a chance to test PushSharp with a p12 file generated **without** the certfile param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to give a CSR file as parameter of `-certfile`.

`-certfile` can be used for adding additional certificates to the store.

For example CA certificates chain of the app_cert.pem:

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in app_cert.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem \
                -certfile ca_certificates.pem -name "MyAppName" -out pushsharp.p12
```

Usually there is no need to use CSR, if the corresponding certificate already exists.

Comment: Thanks for confirming how this should work. No idea how this could have been working for us in the past. Removing the `certfile` argument ended up working just fine with PushSharp.